# Verifying associativity of monoids using number theoretic argument

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, monoid

[image]I'm studying monoids and trying to test whether a given construction is a monoid. Given a set $M=\{x_0, x_1, ..., x_6\}$ and a multiplication $x_i \cdot x_j = x_{i+j-k}$ where $k$ is the largest multiple of 3 contained in $i+j-4$, we want to test whether M is a monoid. Now, $7 \choose 2$ is $21$ so, I first wanted to list all $21$ products $x_0 \cdot x_1$, $x_0 \cdot x_2$, ..., $x_5 \cdot x_6$ and check all $7\choose 3$ combinations but this is obviously impractical. I suspect that I am to use some number theoretic trick to verify associativity but I don't know what it is. Any hints will be helpful.

Comment: "largest multiple of $3$ contained in" means what? Can you give an example to illustrate?

Comment: This question comes from Classic Algebra by P.M Cohn and this is the way it is given but I interpret "largest multiple of 3 in $i+j-4$" to mean the largest factor of $i+j-4$ that is a multiple of 3. That's the only thing that makes sense to me..

Comment: Note that you have commutativity so you can reduce the number of tests.

Comment: The 21 sets I enumerated had no duplicates. Also, any cuts that can be made due to commutativity will still leave a tedious amount of computations to be done.

Comment: If $i+j=4$, there is no largest factor of $i+j−4$ that is a multiple of $3$.

Comment: I suspect it means that you subtract $3m$, where $3m\leq i+j-4\lt 3(m+1)$.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin: With that interpretation, there's no identity element

Comment: @quasi: Huh? I’m guessing it’s only for positive values, and then $x_0+x_i=x_i$, because $0+i-4$ is never both positive and at least $3$ when $0\leq i\leq 6$.

Comment: @Salazar_3854708: Even with Arturo Magidin's proposed interpretation, the definition of the multiplication is not clear to me. But if you understand the definition, it would be very helpful if you could edit your post to show a few sample products.

Comment: So, is $x_2+x_6$ given by looking at $2+6-4=4$, and since $4=3+1$, then you take $x_{2+6-3}=x_5$? And $x_6+x_6$ you look at $6+6-4=8=3(2)+2$, so the value is $x_{6+6-6} = x_6$?

Comment: @Arturo Magidin: Your interpretation works in the sense that you _do_ get a monoid. But I think the author (P. M. Cohn) should have worded the definition less ambigously, and perhaps provided a few sample products so as to avoid misunderstanding.

Comment: @quasi: I would want to see the original, to be honest. I’ve read stuff by P.M. Cohn, and the reported wording does not ring true to me.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin this is Cohn's wording.

Comment: Please see the added picture. It's from this book https://www.amazon.ca/Classic-Algebra-P-M-Cohn/dp/0471877328

Comment: Such language is used occasionally, e.g. "8008, the largest multiple of 1001 contained in 8531" [on p. 31](https://books.google.com/books?id=NbbbL9gMJ88C&pg=PA31&q=%22contained%20in%22) of Beiler's book *Recreations in the Theory of Numbers.* Maybe it occurs from viewing a natural as a  [von Neumann ordinal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Von_Neumann_definition_of_ordinals), i.e. the set of all smaller naturals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay... this is the cyclic monoid generated by $x_1$, with the following rule: you go
$$x_1\to x_2\to x_3\to x_4\to x_5\to x_6\to x_4 \to x_5\to x_6\to x_4\to\cdots$$

In other words: add the indices. If they exceed $x_6$, you wrap back around to $x_4$. That’s why the rule is, essentialy, “subtract the largest (positive) multiple of $3$ less than or equal to $i+j-4$“.

This should make it easy to verify that multiplication is associative; you can pretend that you are just adding indices, but under the further assumption that $4\sim 4+3k$, $5\sim 5+3k$, and $6\sim 6+3k$ with $k\geq 0$ (in fact, it is a quotient of the free monoid in one generator modulo the congruence that makes $x^i\equiv x^j$ if and only if $i=j$ or $i\equiv j\pmod{3}$ and $i,j\geq 4$).

(Every cyclic monoid corresponds to a pair of nonnegative integers $r,s$, with $x^i=x^j$ if and only if $i=j$, or $i,j\geq r$ and $i\equiv j\pmod{s}$; the infinite cyclic monoid, isomorphic to the nonnegative integers, corresponds to $r=s=0$; the trivial monoid to $r=0$, $s=1$; this monoid to $r=4$ and $s=3$).